# Show only clicked view

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this template (a part):

```
       <tbody *ngFor='let list of lists'>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.type_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.gos_prinad_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.disloc_country_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.adm_terr_id }}</td>
                    <td><a (click)="toggleElement()">смотр.</a></td>
                    <td>{{ list.lat }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.lon }}</td>
                    <td>{{ list.alt }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr [hidden]="hideElement" *ngFor="let new_var of list.hops">
                    <td>{{ new_var.hop_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ new_var.id_sl_hop }}</td>
                    <td>{{ new_var.hop_text }}</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

And this is a `toogleElement()` for hide and show some data:

```
toggleElement(){
        if(this.hideElement) {
            this.hideElement = false;
        }else{
            this.hideElement = true;
        }
```

Now, when i press `смотр.` after each line open a new form

```
<tr [hidden]="hideElement" *ngFor="let new_var of list.hops">
                    <td>{{ new_var.hop_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ new_var.id_sl_hop }}</td>
                    <td>{{ new_var.hop_text }}</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
```

But i would that this form are dont repeated after all rows, and open only one by one.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
toggleElement(list){
    list.isVisible= !list.isVisible;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
    <template ngFor let-list [ngForOf]="lists">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ list.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.location }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.type_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.gos_prinad_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.disloc_country_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.adm_terr_id }}</td>
            <td><a (click)="toggleElement(list)">смотр.</a></td>
            <td>{{ list.lat }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.lon }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.alt }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr [hidden]="!list.isVisible" *ngFor="let new_var of list.hops">
            <td>{{ new_var.hop_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ new_var.id_sl_hop }}</td>
            <td>{{ new_var.hop_text }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but now, after upadate a page, my hidden block is show

Comment: That's because the variable isHidden was not initialized so it started as falsy and the content was shown. I edited the code to use a isVisible variable now.